# Distinguish 'inf' and '-inf'

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, nan, infinite

How can I separate `inf` and `-inf` from each other?

I have matrix that contains `inf` and `-inf` and I want to replace them with `1e6` and `-1e6` respectively.

for example,

```
a = [1 2 3 0 3 4]./[1 1 1 0 1 0];
b = log2([0 2 1 2 1 2]);
c = cat(1,a,b);
```

which is,

```
c = [  1     2     3   NaN     3   Inf;
    -Inf     1     0     1     0     1];
```

I want,

```
newc = [   1   2   3   NaN   3   1e6;
        -1e6   1   0     1   0     1];
```

I couldn't find a function that separates them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can detect `inf` using `isinf()`, and you can detect sign using `sign()`. Combine the two:

```
newc = c;
inf_filter = isinf(newc);
newc(inf_filter) = 1e6 * sign(newc(inf_filter));
```